# Change Django template loop behavior based on browser window size

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates, media-queries

my web app uses a Django template for loop to display 52 weeks of a year on one line.  Once 52 weeks have been displayed, I use a `<br>` tag to break line and start the weeks of the next year.  This works great on large screens, but when I reduce screen size less than 1200px (Bootstrap xl setting) the nice-looking line breaks and then the overflow fills the next line, creating an uneven break.

For browser window size greater than 1200px, I would like to continue displaying 52 weeks as denoted by a monotype character (in this case "X" and "O").

For browser window semi less than 1200px, I would like to display each line with only 13 weeks (52 divided by 4) such that one "year" takes up four rows.

Here is the code I have:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<p class="text-monospace">
    {% for week in week_list %}
    {% if week.is_current_week %}
    <a href="{% url 'week_view' week.week_number %}">H</a>
    {% elif week.is_past %}
    <a href="{% url 'week_view' week.week_number %}">X</a>
    {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'week_view' week.week_number %}">O</a>
    {% endif %}

    {% if week.week_number|divisibleby:"52" %}
    <br>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</p>

{% endblock %}
```

I know some javascript but not much CSS.  what would be the best way to tackle this problem?  In some of my searches I see responses "use a media query".  If that's the way then great! I'm just not sure how to link it with the Django templating language.  Thanks for the help.

[image: happiness]

[image: sadness]

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring out how to implement this with the Bootstrap grid system.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row no-gutters text-monospace">
    <div class="col-xl-3-m-0 col-lg-12-m-0">
        {% for week in week_list %}


        {% if week.is_current_week %}
        <a href="{% url 'week_view' week.week_number %}">H</a>
        {% elif week.is_past %}
        <a href="{% url 'week_view' week.week_number %}">X</a>
        {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'week_view' week.week_number %}">O</a>
        {% endif %}

        {% if week.week_number|divisibleby:"52" %}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row no-gutters text-monospace">
    <div class="col-xl-3-m-0 col-lg-12-m-0">
        {% elif week.week_number|divisibleby:"13" %}
    </div>&nbsp;
    <div class="col-xl-3-m-0 col-lg-12-m-0">
        {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```